# Java Accessing method from alternate class

Tags: java, class, methods, reference

I have classes A and B, I want to access a method from class A in class B but it isn't working, I'm getting the following message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

The particular part that is causing this is when accessing `ba`:

```
ba.getBalance() >= LIM        
ba.debit(LIM);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I've created the private field and initialised it within main.

**Class B:**

```
 public class B {

        private A ba;
        private long balance;

        public B(long amount, A ba){
        }

        public boolean testCase(long amount){
           //..
        }

    public long getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }
```

**Class A:**

```
public class A {

     private long balance;

     public A(long amount){
    }

    public boolean debit(long amount){
        //.. simple arithmetic 
    }

    public long getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }
```

**Main**

```
A aa = new BankAccount(amount1); // where amounts are user input
B bb = new GoCardAccount(amount2, aa);
```

Comment: You need to assign the instance of  `ba` you are passing to `B` constructor to your private field member `ba`, as you do for `amount`:
`public B(long amount, A ba) { this.ba = ba; this.balance = amount }`

Answer (score 0):

you forget to set `ba` in the constructor

```
    public B(long amount, A ba){
        balance = amount;
        this.ba = ba;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in B constructor 
this.ba=ba . You are not assigning any value to A , so it throws NPE